# What is the correct way to decorate an external (library) function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I'm using a library function several times in my code which tests for a pass/fail condition and executes different code accordingly, but for some reason does not have a return value for the result it finds; I'd like to add this with a decorator so that I can call it in my code.

What is the correct way to do this given that I cannot edit the source file?

Should I do something like:

```
def test_pass(param1, param2):
    external_function(param1, param2)
    if(...):
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Or is there a way to use the nice @decorator syntax?

Comment: Why not just wrap the function? `@decorator` is just syntactic sugar, but to enhance an external function, just create a wrapper that calls the external function for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decorating with `@decorator` is *syntactic sugar*; the function object is replaced by whatever the `decorator(orig_function)` call returns.

For external functions, you'd just use the wrapper you wrote; you'd only use the decorator syntax when defining the original function.