# Is there a "pythonic" way to adjust a function's definition?

Tags: python

I'm working with a module that uses `useful_function(obj)` a lot. My problem is that I want `useful_function` to behave slightly differently than normal. Currently, I'm using the following method to solve my problem:

```
original_useful_function = useful_function

def useful_function(obj):
    if meets_criteria(obj):
        return my_desired_result(obj)
    return original_useful_function(obj)
```

I can then go about my work knowing that every invocation of `useful_function` will behave the way I want. However, I'm curious if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: I'm thinking on decorators too. However, I think it is not suitable for the problem OP is asking since it would require redefining the function anyways, or directly calling the decorator, so it would have the same level of indirection as currently.

Comment: Can you give some context, more specifics about your particular use case? As a generic question this seems fine, but it's possible that the details will allow for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, though I always worry that adding context will render the quesiton off-topic in some users minds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to decorate an external (library) function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25240221/2311167)

Comment: The _"Pythonic"_ way would be to follow the Zen of Python, which says _"Explicit is better than implicit"_, _"Simple is better than complex_", and _"Readability counts"_. Therefore, make a completely new function with a completely different name and use that one. Make it clear what is going on.

Comment: @zvone Unfortunately this is not an option. I can't edit the code that uses `useful_function`. Maybe this falls under *practicality beats purity*.

Answer (score 0):

I just can think on defining a lambda, but that's about it, and I think there is no easy way of escaping reassigning the useful_function, unless the method is in a class and we do some magic tricks with `__getattribute__`...

```py
original_useful_function = useful_function
useful_function = lambda obj: my_desired_result(obj) if meets_criteria(obj) else original_useful_function(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing a lot of this, you could consider a decorator.

Other than that I think what you have is clear and direct.

BTW, it seems like you might be using import * from foo?  It's usually better to use import foo.

Comment: How would one decorate a function defined elsewhere?

Comment: @JohnKugelman You wouldn't.  What's your point?  I get it.  You think the decorator would be applied to something it's not.

Comment: @JohnKugelman decorators are just functions, after all. `@`-style is just a syntax sugar for `module.useful_function = my_decorator(module.useful_function)`

Comment: I'm saying where do you put the decorator? The OP isn't defining the function, they're modifying it. Where does the `@` go? A code example would help.